# "Could not resolve host: github.com" error when trying to run "git pull" in iTerm2

Tags: macos, mac, git, iterm2, macos-catalina

I ran into this error when trying to pull the latest contents of a repository in iTerm2. Removing the origin and re-adding it did not resolve the issue. However, restarting iTerm2 completely resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Quitting out of iTerm2 and restarting it completely resolved the issue.

Comment: This doesn’t make sense.  You probably had a network glitch that went away while you were restarting the terminal.

Comment: @Scott the internet was working fine otherwise, and the problem persisted for an extended period of time, so restarting is what fixed the issue.